# Swift Gmail API: Try to send message gives error -1001

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, gmail-api, gtm-oauth2

I'm trying to send a gmail message in Swift using the `GoogleAPIClientForREST` and `GTMOAuth2` libraries but I'm getting the aforementioned error.

Here's my code:

```
    let message = GTLRGmail_Message()
    message.raw = "test"
    let query = GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesSend.query(withObject: message, userId: "example@gmail.com", uploadParameters: nil)
    let gmailService = GTLRGmailService()
    let auth = GTMOAuth2Authentication()
    auth.clientID = gmailClientID
    gmailService.authorizer = auth
    gmailService.executeQuery(query) { ticket, object, error in
        print(ticket)
        print(object)
        print(error)
    }
```

and here's the error:

```
Optional(Error Domain=com.google.GTMOAuth2 Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={request=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x600000016ed0> { URL: https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/example%40gmail.com/messages/send?prettyPrint=false }})
```

**Notes:**

- I used "example@gmail.com" for sake of asking the question, I'm using a real email in my app.
- I followed all the basic steps in [Google's tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios)

Comment: there may be a mistake in you calling url, check its sending parameters too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19095861/665689 refer this

Comment: @vaibhav why would there be a mistake in my calling url? I didn't manipulate any url myself, only used the sdk.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya i've tried the solution in your referenced answer. did not work.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send read this document carefully

Comment: @rigdonmr then probably you are missing to take some permissions to use the api or you can use mfmailcomposer for that plenty of examples available.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I read that extremely carefully and did not learn anything new. Are you trying to point me to something?

Comment: @vaibhav mfmailcomposer is GUI. I'm looking for a way to send it in the background. I don't see how I could be missing permissions when I followed Google's own tutorial exactly.

Comment: ohh, now you mentioned here looking solution for background, let me see if could provide any solution for that.

Comment: The code clearly reads that it's in the background

Comment: @rigdonmr, unfortunately Apple doesn't allow to send email's while app is in background and we didnt found anywhere background process leads ambiguity, now i am willing to know from where you found such method using `GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesSend` which enables a user to send mails in background.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've integrated `GTMOAuth2` properly into your app by following this [tutorial](https://github.com/chrhansen/simple-oauth2). Be sure to register the Platform as `Other` and NOT `iOS` otherwise you'll get "invalid_client" error when authenticating.

You may also check the given solution on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095861/google-oauth-error-1001/19649048#19649048).

Comment: tried that tutorial, then tried cloning the repo and using that. both did not work. I've seen the other question you've posted. basically says the same thing. the solution is not working for me.

Comment: By using `other` instead of `iOS` you have to include your secret key, not very safe...